# Rails: Best way to implement dynamic email contents and layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to have functionality where admin can easily change the content/copy of emails, designer can easily change the design and layouts

I am thinking about mailchimp templates (& Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content) but I found some limitations over there like can not share common code across the templates (header /footer) , can not set subject of templates and many more..

So I want to make simple admin panel where I show the email templates stored in database and users can edit the copy of email/ do html css changes/ can preview the email / can send test email, I will also display some dynamic text varibles so that users can use those as well like 
 `{{ first_name }}`

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am using Mandrill after some try on other alternatives There are few reasons why I am able to decide

1. Very good html editor
2. Block helpers available in Mandrill (if-else, loops) Like LIQUID
3. I can share templates from mailchimp to mandrill
4. Outbound Logs and templates will be at one place
5. I can use draft functionality of templates to make new design before publishing it

Here are some useful links you should try

1. http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html
2. https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content